# How to pass headers with PouchDB sync requests?

Tags: pouchdb

I've tried every possibility I found for this, without success. The modern way to do this is supposed to be this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/foo', {
    fetch: function (url, opts) {
        opts.headers.set('X-Some-Special-Header', 'foo');
        return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
    }
});

PouchDB.sync(pouch, remoteDb)
```

This works in sofar as the headers actually get passed, but it breaks CORS. If you remove the fetch code, CORS works.

There are two other ways you're supposedly able to pass the headers: In the sync options, or directly when creating the DB. But neither works.

Comment: What CORS error are you getting in the browser?

Comment: ```Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5984/amadeuspagel/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.```